# Construct Special matrix in mathematica

Tags: matrix

I want to define $D = [d_{ij}]$ as the $(N+1) \times (N+1)$ lower triangular matrix given by the following recursive definitions:

$$
\begin{aligned}
d_{i,i-1} &= i, \qquad\qquad \qquad i=1,2,\dots, N \\
d_{i,0}   &= -3d_{i-2,0}-2 \qquad i=3,5,...,k; k= \begin{cases} 
      N & \text{N is odd} \\
      N-1 & \text{N is even}
   \end{cases} \\
d_{2n+1,i+1} &= d_{2n+1-1,i}+1 \qquad i =0,1,\dots, N-2n; n = 2,3,\dots, \lfloor N/2 \rfloor \\
 d_{i,j} &= 0 \qquad \qquad \qquad \text{otherwise}
\end{aligned}
$$

For example:
For N=4

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {-5, 0, 3, 0,0}, {0, -4, 0, 4, 0}} // MatrixForm
```

For N=5

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-5, 0,3, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -4, 0, 4, 0, 0}, {13, 0, -3, 0, 5,0}} // MatrixForm
```

For N=6

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0}, {-5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0},{13, 0, -3, 0,5, 0, 0}, {0, 14, 0, -2, 0, 6, 0}} // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Edit 01:

Let's wrap up the recursive construction in a function and use it to "infer" the diagonal structure at large `N`:

```
recursiveConstruction[n_] := Module[{d$},
  d$[__] := 0;
  d$[i_, j_] := j /; j == i - 1;
  Do[d$[i + 1, 1] = -3 d$[i - 1, 1] - 2, {i, 3, If[OddQ[n], n, n +1],2}];
  Do[d$[2 m + i + 1, i + 2] = d$[2 m + i, i + 1] + 1, {m, 2,Floor[n/2]}, {i, 0, n - 2 m}];
  Array[d$, {n + 1, n + 1}]]

MatrixForm[recursiveConstruction[12]]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -5 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -4 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 13 & 0 & -3 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 14 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -41 & 0 & 15 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -40 & 0 & 16 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 121 & 0 & -39 & 0 & 17 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 122 & 0 & -38 & 0 & 18 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 0 \\
 -365 & 0 & 123 & 0 & -37 & 0 & 19 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 11 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

It's clear we need the even subdiagonals, which start at a particular value and increment by one. We'll be lazy and find a formula for the starting value using [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html):

```
diagonalStartingFormula[n_] = 
 FindSequenceFunction[
  Thread[{Range[2, 13, 2], 
    recursiveConstruction[12][[2 ;; -1 ;; 2, 1]]}], n]
```

which returns $\frac{1}{2} \left(-1-i^n 3^{n/2}\right)$.

We can now wrap all this in a function using [`Band`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html) and [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html):

```
bandedConstruction[n_] := 
 Block[{diagonalStartingValues, diagonalStartingPositions, diagonalOffsets, diagonalRanges, diagonalBands},
  diagonalStartingPositions = Range[2, n + 1, 2];
  diagonalStartingValues = diagonalStartingFormula[diagonalStartingPositions];
  diagonalOffsets = n + 1 - # & /@ diagonalStartingPositions;
  diagonalRanges = MapThread[Range[#1, #1 + #2] &, {diagonalStartingValues, diagonalOffsets}];
  diagonalBands = MapThread[Band[{#1, 1}] -> #2 &, {diagonalStartingPositions, diagonalRanges}];
  SparseArray[diagonalBands, {n + 1, n + 1}]
  ]
```

which indeed agrees with our recursive construction.

### Original Post

First, note that the WL is one-indexed, and your recursive definitions seem to be zero-indexed.

The following seems to do what you want:

```
Clear[n,d]
n = 6;
d[__] := 0;
d[i_, j_] := j /; j == i - 1;
Do[d[i + 1, 1] = -3 d[i - 1, 1] - 2, {i, 3, If[OddQ[n], n, n + 1], 2}];
Do[d[2 m + i + 1, i + 2] = d[2 m + i, i + 1] + 1, {m, 2, Floor[n/2]}, {i, 0, n - 2 m}]

MatrixForm[Array[d, {n + 1, n + 1}]]
```

That being said, it seems to me this should be easier to construct using rules for even band-diagonals. E.g. for N=6 using something like:

```
With[{n = 6},
 MatrixForm[SparseArray[{
    Band[{2, 1}] -> Range[n],
    Band[{4, 1}] -> Range[-5, n - 8, 1],
    Band[{6, 1}] -> Range[13, 13 + n - 5]
    }, {n + 1, n + 1}]]
 ]
```

Comment: (+1) very nicely done. Just a question. Why not `Table` with `If` conditions? Are there any immediate disadvantages or was it a personal preference?

Comment: As formulated, I'm not sure this can be done in one go, since some of the definitions are recursive. As I highlighted above though, the matrix has very obvious diagonal structure one could leverage

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I might have a go a bit later to see if it can be done in a single `Table`. Thanks again

Comment: Many thanks, please for N=4, the second way using band is not working!!!

Comment: Also, using band did not give the same matrices....

Comment: The original post was only giving an example for $N=6$. Have a look now, updated it to package both the recursive and banded constructions in more generalized functions

Comment: Thank you for your great help.

Comment: @GeorgeVarnavides unfortunately I did not have enough time to work on this. If you are interested the closest I could go with the single `Table` is given here: `f[x_?Negative, y_] := 0
f[x_, y_?Negative] := 0
f[x_?Negative, y_?Negative] := 0
test[n_] := LowerTriangularize[
  Table[
   If[j == i - 1, f[i, j] = i,
      If[(j == 0) && (Mod[i, 2] == 1), f[i, j] = -3 f[i - 2, 0] - 2,
        If[(j == i + 1) && (i = 2 n + 1), 
      f[i, j] = f[2 n + 1 - 1, i] + 1,
      0]
     ]
    ]
   , {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}
   ],
  -1]`

Comment: As you can see I messed up somewhere on condition and for `n=4` I am missing one element from the matrix. In any case, I thought you might wanted to have a look and improve it if you have the time. Your solution is quite spectacular!